# Measuring performance in Leave One Subject Out Cross-validation

Tags: validation, machine-learning, neural-network, cross-validation, training-data

I am designing a neural network (100 inputs - 100 hidden units - 100 outputs) for a regression problem. I am using ADAM as optimizer and dropout with rate 0.3 for regularization.

Training data proceeds from 5 different subjects so I am using LOSO-Cross-validation to evaluate different combinations of hyperparameters (batch size, number of epochs and learning rate).

So, for example, considering subject 1: 
I train the network using features from subjects 2-5 (lets call it X_cv_train) and evaluate its performance using subject 1 (lets call it X_cv_valid).

The issue is, after performing the LOSO-XV, for some of the subjects, the MSE computed on the validation set of their fold is substantially higher than the MSE computed on their training set.

For example, for subject 1, MSE on X_cv_train is 0.009 and MSE on X_cv_valid is 0.013 (seems reasonable) but for subject 3, MSE on X_cv_train is 0.008 and MSE on X_cv_valid is 0.04 (seems too high).

The average MSE on the training set is 0.009 while the average MSE on the validation set is 0.022.

Which would be the correct way to proceed?